# Cast string column into numeric

Tags: r, casting, binary, dataset

My data set Smarket (from library ISLR) has a column Direction like

```
  Direction    
1  Up       
2  Down      
3  Down      
4  Up       
5  Down       
6  Up
```

How do I cast it to a binary column like

```
  Direction    
1  0       
2  1       
3  1       
4  0      
5  1       
6  0
```

Doing the following I don't get anything. What am I supposed to do?

```
data <- Smarket 
data$Direction <- as.factor(as.numeric(data$Direction))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1$binary <- as.integer( df1$Direction == 'Down' )
df1
#   Direction binary
# 1        Up      0
# 2      Down      1
# 3      Down      1
# 4        Up      0
# 5      Down      1
# 6        Up      0
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Direction = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
                                            .Label = c("Down", "Up"),
                                            class = "factor")),
                 .Names = "Direction", class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```